# Git manage parallel branch after master update

Tags: git

I am working on a Git repository where we have a `private` branch on top of the `master` branch,
where we have commits which cannot be made public yet. Sometimes we can publish some commits which we have to cherry-pick

```sh
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 6afeff5
...
```

We then often apply some rebase before creating a tag `tag X.X.X`/release and pushing the `master` branch back to the repository. The question is, how we best base our `private` branch on the `master` branch again after such a procedure (The history should reflect that `private` is now ahead of `tag X.X.X`). If I was working alone on the `private` branch, I would simply `rebase` and `push --force-with-lease`. But with collaborators that is not a good idea.

The other option coming to my mind, is creating after every such `master` release a new branch

```sh
git checkout master
git checkout -b private_X.X.X
```

and then apply the changes in `private` which I didn't cherry-pick yet on `private_X.X.X`. Applying just

```
git checkout private_X.X.X
git merge private
```

would result in duplicate commits for the ones I already cherry-picked.
Does git provide in automatic solution for this workflow?

Or is there an alternative workflow, fulfilling our requirements (using a private branch and only selectively publish commits from this branch) much is easier to manage?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _would result in duplicate commits for the ones I already cherry-picked_ / what's the issue with this?
Merging two branches with shared/cherry-picked commits should be no problem?

Comment: Indeed, there is no problem with merging. Just the history becomes increasingly confusing as some commits are double.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a standard two-track development flow:

- `master` is used only for releases, and gets tags.
- `private` is used for development, and occasionally gets merged into `master`.
- Everyone working on `private` must make a branch; no one must commit directly onto `private` except as a merge from a branch. (Typically these will be through PRs.)

In this way, there is no need for the rebasing you speak of. Whenever the time comes to merge `private` into `master`, you can do a two-way merge if necessary (`master` into `private`, then `private` into `master`) if there is a need to bring `private` further up to date; if you are going to play cherry-pick games, that should straighten things out.

Comment: The problem is that we cannot merge the `private` branch. We can only cherry-pick certain features of it, the rest has to remain private. We also only know a posteriori which features will be included in `master`.   You mean cherry-picking becomes easier if commits to `private` are only merges?

Comment: If you can't merge `private` as a whole, it seems to me that the solution is just the first part of the two-way merge I describe: merge `master` into `private` and _don't_ merge `private` into `master`. However, I should say that I find this a very strange workflow.

Comment: I agree it is a strange workflow, and I am definitely not happy with it. But I don't know a better solution.

Comment: Then maybe _ask_ about a better solution? Perhaps that should have been the question all along...?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing some of your requirements here but IMHO this should be possible with simply merging `master` into `private`:

- You do your development work on `private`
- `git cherry-pick` commits you want to publish from `private` to `master`
- `git tag` the new master for release
- `git merge master` into `private`
- repeat

With this your branch tree would look like this:

```
* d781719 (private) feature 6
*   737a64b Merge branch 'master' into private
|\  
| * e1f50e4 (tag: v0.2, master) feature 5
* | 8828158 feature 5
* | 84a90db feature 4
* | c1ca6cb private feature 2
* | 3b12ad7 Merge branch 'master' into private
|\| 
| * 9c9466f (tag: v0.1) feature 3
| * c661974 feature 2
* | 15285bc feature 3
* | 2ef63d0 private feature 1
* | fd38cee feature 2
* | 9214751 feature 1
* | 52ff609 private config
|/  
* 1bd58c9 initial commit
```

While the `master` branch alone looks like this

```
* e1f50e4 (tag: v0.2, master) feature 5
* 9c9466f (tag: v0.1) feature 3
* c661974 feature 2
* 1bd58c9 initial commit
```

With [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) you can then see which commits from `private` are still missing in `master`, i.e. were not `cherry-pick`ed yet.

If you have issues with recurring merge conflicts, have a look into [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere).

Comment: Thanks for telling about `git cherry`, it is very useful indeed. But as far as I see it compares the SHA, right? So if I do a refactor, it doesn't detect that the commit is already included.

Comment: Since cherry-picking a commit will _always_ change its SHA this would be quite useless then. Instead `git cherry` uses [`git patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) to calculate the identifier of a commit based on the actual changes it introduces.